# Why is my .htaccess redirect not working? RedirectMatch 301 "^news\/[0-9]+-(.*)" "headlines\/$1" [L,R=302]

Tags: regex, .htaccess

My .htaccess redirect isn't working.

Here is my RegEx

```bash
RedirectMatch 301 "^news\/[0-9]+-(.*)" "headlines\/$1"  [L,R=302]
```

I used this site to generate it and it all seems to work on that site.
https://regex101.com/r/Yq7VSF/1

We are migrating the website and the "news" category has been renamed to "headlines".
Furthermore, the numbers at the beginning of the final stem of the URL will be removed.

So

> `http://tek.squareballoon.co.uk/news/122-windows-10-the-final-countdown`

Will become

> `http://tek.squareballoon.co.uk/headlines/windows-10-the-final-countdown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed syntax of `RedirectMatch` with `RewiteRule`. You may use this

```bash
RedirectMatch 302 ^/news/[0-9]+-(.*) /headlines/$1
```

Remember that a leading slash is not stripped in the URI pattern in `RedirectMatch` directive as in the `RewriteRule`.

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` with `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: For some reason it's redirecting to this URL `http://tek.squareballoon.co.uk/headlines/122-windows-10-the-final-countdown` so it's still not removing the numbers.

Comment: That could be due to old browser cache. Test using a command line tool like curl or wget or else completely clear browser cache. I have tested with `/news/122-windows-10-the-final-countdown` and got redirected to `/headlines/windows-10-the-final-countdown`

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectMatch` does not support flags like `[L,R=302]`. These are of `RewriteRule` (of `mod_rewrite`). So try using the latter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-(.*)$ /headlines/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Also you mentioned both 301 and 302 redirects which is quite contradictary.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I have made another error, my URL doesn't start with `/news` it starts with `https://tek.squareballoon.co.uk` the reason I was trying to avoid using the entire URL is because it's on a test site and I wanted it to work after I went live where the domain would change but not the end part of the URL.  Stem?  So I'm guessing `^` won't work

Comment: In RewriteRule, the pattern matches against the path after the domain name, so you don't need to adjust for different domains as the rule doesn't include the domain part of the URL.